# How do I access promise callback value outside of the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It is to my understanding that callback functions are asynchronous and cannot return a value like regular functions. Upon reading about promises, I thought I grasped a good understanding about them, that they are basically an enhanced version of callbacks that allows returning a value like asynchronous function. In my `getConnections` method, I am attempting to call the `find()` function on my database through mongoose, and I am attempting to grab this array of objects and send it to the views.

```js
var test =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Database.find().then(list => {
            resolve(list);

        }).catch(err=> {
            return reject(err);
        })

        })
console.log(test)
```

When I attempt to log to the console outside of the promise function, I get `Promise { _U: 0, _V: 0, _W: null, _X: null }`

I don't think this is functioning correctly, and I thought I utilized promises correctly. Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to return this array of objects outside of the callback function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Try this instead: `test.then(x=> console.log(x));`. [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) is the normal mechanism to get the result of the promise once it resolves.

Comment: Well I get the console log but I want to access this variable outside the document and send it to views.

Comment: rethink your code ... think like this ... *asynchrony can not be made synchronous, because I'm writing javascript, not developing a time machine* :D

Comment: *send it to views* sounds something you could wrap into `then()`.

Comment: `Database.find().then(list => list)` <-- list is what you need

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add `await` before the promise declaration.
i.e.

```
var test = await new Promise...
```

Comment: await can be used only in an async function. Check @Yavor's answer

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that when you write a function like this:

```
const getData = async () => { const response = await fetch(someUrl, {}, {}); return response;}
```

Then you also need to `await` that function when you call it. Like this:

```
const setData = async () => { const dataToSet = await getData(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let test =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Database.find().then(list => {
            resolve(list);

        }).catch(err=> {
            return reject(err);
        })

        })

test
.then(result=>console.log(result))
```

Should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var someValue;
    var test =  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Database.find().then(list => {
           resolve(list);

         }).catch(err=> {
           return reject(err);
       })

    }).then(res => {
      someValue=res;
    })

   console.log(someValue);
```