# fetch API always returns {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, react-native, fetch

The below code always return the below wired object

> {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

as response.

Here is my code

```
    getData = () => {
        fetch('http://192.168.64.1:3000/getAll',{
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('Response:')
            console.log(response.json())
            console.info('=================================')
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));

    } 

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getData();
    }
```

I am using node, express, Mysql as backend and react-native frontend

my backend code is here

```
app.get('/getAll',(req,res) => {
    console.log('getAll method Called');
    con.query('select * from dummy',(err,results,fields) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('Response');
        console.log(results);
        res.send(results);
    });
});
```

The above code gives correct output in console but fetch API is not.

i cant find solution for the my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you use for backend server ?

Comment: i am using node and express

Comment: Have you looked in the network tab of the browser's debugging tools to see what the raw payload looks like?

Comment: i am working on react-native bro

Comment: `response.json()` returns a promise.

Comment: What R those _U, _V, _W, _X? I get those too but with my correct response data inside the _W. These are not part of my back-end.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

That indicates that you are logging the promise before it resolves - the result of when you:
`console.log(response.json())`

[How do I access promise callback value outside of the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281739/how-do-i-access-promise-callback-value-outside-of-the-function)

As @Evert rightfully pointed out in comments, this is because response.json() returns a promise object.

So, you'll need to chain an additional `.then()` after you call `response.json()` where you log the resolved promise.

```
getData = () => {
    fetch('http://192.168.64.1:3000/getAll',{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add *async* and *await* to your code:

```
getData = async () => {
   await fetch('http://192.168.64.1:3000/getAll',{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('Response:')
        console.log(response.json())
        console.info('=================================')
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that you are not waiting for your Promise to resolve and this can be solved easily.

```
try {
  const res = await fetch(
    'your_api',
  );
  const data = await res.json();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So the issue is that you are not waiting for your Promise to resolve. Have added `await` and that'll go next line once the await action is completed.

```
const user_fun = async (userId) => {
  const response = await fetch("url");
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log("users ", data);
  return data;
};
let data = user_fun();
console.log("users ", data);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.