# How to provide JSON file as source to LottieView

Tags: react-native, lottie

I'm building an app in React Native in which I am using LottieFiles. If I provide it with locally stored `.json` file it works fine:

```
<LottieView style={styles.container} source={require('../Assets/Animations/city.json')} autoPlay loop />
```

But I try to do the same thing using a URL:

```
<LottieView style={styles.container} source={{ uri: 'https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_0apkn3k1.json' }} autoPlay loop />
```

I've even tried saving the Lottiefile in Firebase Storage and providing that URL but the error I get is:

> Invariant Violation: [7549,"LottieAnimationView",1,{"progress":0,"speed":1,"loop":true,"resizeMode":"contain","sourceJson":"{"uri":"https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_0apkn3k1.json"}","onAnimationFinish":true,"onLayout":true,"aspectRatio":"<>","position":"absolute","left":0,"right":0,"top":0,"bottom":0}] is not usable as a native method argument

**UPDATE 1**

I'm fetching the JSON like this:

```
    const [jsonRet, setJsonRet] = useState({});

    getData = () => {
        fetch('https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_0apkn3k1.json', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
            console.log('DATA IS: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            setJsonRet(data)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
        });
    }

    getData()
```

It works as to where I have consol.log I can see a long JSON response which looks like how Lottie JSON files are then I use `jsonRet` as:

```
<LottieView source={jsonRet} autoPlay loop />
```

I am using https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native package.

The errors I'm getting are:

> Invariant Violation: [77,"LottieAnimationView",591,{"loop":true,"progress":0,"speed":1,"resizeMode":"contain","sourceJson":"{}","onAnimationFinish":true,"onLayout":true,"aspectRatio":"<>","position":"absolute","left":0,"right":0,"top":0,"bottom":0}] is not usable as a native method argument

And

> Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried it like this and it's printing the right JSON but putting it in `LottieView` fails:

```
    const [jsonRet, setJsonRet] = useState({});

    getData = () => {
        fetch('https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_0apkn3k1.json', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
            console.log('DATA IS: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            setJsonRet(data)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
        });
    }

    getData()
```

Then I put it in `LottieView` as:

```
<LottieView source={jsonRet} autoPlay loop />
```

The errors:

> Invariant Violation: [77,"LottieAnimationView",1,{"loop":true,"progress":0,"speed":1,"resizeMode":"contain","sourceJson":"{}","onAnimationFinish":true,"onLayout":true,"aspectRatio":"<>","position":"absolute","left":0,"right":0,"top":0,"bottom":0}] is not usable as a native method argument

and

> Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native/issues/682), you can fetch a JSON from a API, or something like that, and use it like as follow:

```js
let somejson = fetch("<jsonURL>")

render(){

    {
        !somejson ? null : <LottieView source={somejson} autoPlay loop />
    } 
}
```

If you dont have any API to fetch from, you can probably:

First: Fetch a .JSON file from somewhere, using [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) or [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs).

Second: Read the JSON file with something like this:

`const customData = require('./customData.json')`

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452822/how-to-fetch-data-from-local-json-file-on-react-native)

Then, use it as said on the beginning of the answer!

[EDIT]

The error you're getting, it's on the `fetch` part of the code, wich ou can do like this:

```js
async function getLottieJSON(){

  return fetch("https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_0apkn3k1.json", {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    return json;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    return(error)
  });
}
```

Then, call it on a async function, probably:

```js
let somejson = await getLottieJSON()
```

More about the `Fetch` function [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network).

Comment: I did `let cityJSON = fetch('GET', 'https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_0apkn3k1.json');` and then `{ !cityJSON ? null : <LottieView style={styles.container} source={cityJSON} autoPlay /> }` but its giving the same error and some new warnings like `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection`

Comment: Modified my answer, Hope it helps!

Comment: I get your point and have tried the edited version but it still didn't work. Firstly this URL `https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_0apkn3k1.json` is not an API returning it's a simple JSON file, and then the `await` was giving an error removing it gave me four errors... 1st is `[TypeError: Already read]` (In fetch.umd.js), 2nd one reads `Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS field sizes are different.` 3rd is `[77,"LottieAnimationView", 241, {"loop"....] is not usable as a native method argument.` and 4th one is also the same as 3rd.

Comment: It seems it should work as it's a straightforward JSON file, but it does not seem to work that way.

Comment: Can you try it again? Updated my answer once more!

Comment: I copied the function as it is and then outside of the function I was using `const somejson = getLottieJSON()` and after that I simply did `console.log(somejson)` and it prints out `{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}`. If I add await it says that it's a reserved word as I'm not using it inside an `async` function, but anyhow it also didn't work when I put it in `<LottieView source={somejson} autoPlay loop />`

Comment: looks like it needs a `.then()`. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906396/fetch-api-always-returns-u-0-v-0-w-null-x-null/64906615

Comment: I started getting the right JSON but when I place it in `LottieView` it fails. I've updated my questions kindly see now.