# Problem when trying to use AsyncStorage with react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, asyncstorage

I am new to react native and I tried to make my first app. I am in the process of making the login/signup pages. I am trying to use AsyncStorage to make the app remember the user. I tested out this code-

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image, Button, Pressable, ScrollView  } from 'react-native';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';








export default function Login(props) {

  const message = props.navigation.getParam('message', null)
  const [ username, setUsername ] = useState("")
  const [ password, setPassword ] = useState("")

  setStringValue = async(value, user) => {
    try {
      
      await AsyncStorage.setItem( user, value)
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  const getData = async (user) => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(user)
      if(value !== null) {
        return value
      } else {
        return false
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  

  const log = () => {

    fetch(`http://192.168.5.223:8000/home/login/`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": 'application/json'
         },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password}),
  })
  .then( res => res.json())
  .then( res => {
    console.log(res)
    
    if (res.valid === true){

      setStringValue(username, username)

      let ch = getData(username)

      console.log(ch)
      

      
      
      
      
      if (res.set === true){
        props.navigation.navigate("Home", {"user": username})
      } else {
        props.navigation.navigate("Profile", {"user": username})
      }
      
    } else {
      props.navigation.navigate("Login", {'message': "username/password are incorrect"})
    }
    

  })
  .catch( error => console.log(error))
  



  



  }

  const sign = () => {

    props.navigation.navigate("Signup")

  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.scroll} >
      <View style={styles.main}>
      <Text style={styles.error}>{message}</Text>  
      <Text style={styles.label}>
        Username: 
      </Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Username" 
        onChangeText={ text => setUsername(text)} value={username}
        autoCapitalize={'none'}
         />
      
      <Text style={styles.label}>Password:</Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Password" onChangeText={ text => setPassword(text)}
        value={password} secureTextEntry={true} autoCapitalize={'none'}
      />

      
      <Button onPress={ () => log()} title="Login"></Button>
      </View>
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        <Button onPress={ () => sign()} title="Don't have an acount? Sign up now" />
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto"/>
    </View>


  )


}

Login.navigationOptions = screenProps => ({
  headerLeft: () => null,
  gestureEnabled: false,
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
  headerTintColor: 'white',

})
```

But the AsyncStorage logged -

Promise {

"_U": 0,

"_V": 0,

"_W": null,

"_X": null,

}
How can I get this to work?

Comment: Without running the code, is there a reason you are not awaiting the fetch call?
`const log = async() => { await fetch /*...*/ }).then(...etc...)`?

Comment: I didn't know if it matters

Comment: The object you're getting back is a pending promise. Async code has to be awaited or you can use .then syntax

Comment: You can find the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906396/fetch-api-always-returns-u-0-v-0-w-null-x-null/64906615#64906615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**getData** and **setStringValue** are asynchronous functions.
So you have to put await before calling them
and also mark callback function as async.

so Please try this log function

```
const log = () => {

    fetch(`http://192.168.5.223:8000/home/login/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }),
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then( async (res) => {
            console.log(res)

            if (res.valid === true) {

                await setStringValue(username, username)

                let ch = await getData(username)

                console.log(ch)

                if (res.set === true) {
                    props.navigation.navigate("Home", { "user": username })
                } else {
                    props.navigation.navigate("Profile", { "user": username })
                }

            } else {
                props.navigation.navigate("Login", { 'message': "username/password are incorrect" })
            }

        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

}
```

Full Code

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image, Button, Pressable, ScrollView } from 'react-native';


export default function Login(props) {

    const message = props.navigation.getParam('message', null)
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

    const setStringValue = async (value, user) => {
        try {

            await AsyncStorage.setItem(user, value)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    const getData = async (user) => {
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(user)
            if (value !== null) {
                return value
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    const log = () => {

        fetch(`http://192.168.5.223:8000/home/login/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }),
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(async (res) => {
                console.log(res)

                if (res.valid === true) {

                    await setStringValue(username, username)

                    let ch = await getData(username)

                    console.log(ch)

                    if (res.set === true) {
                        props.navigation.navigate("Home", { "user": username })
                    } else {
                        props.navigation.navigate("Profile", { "user": username })
                    }

                } else {
                    props.navigation.navigate("Login", { 'message': "username/password are incorrect" })
                }

            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))

    }

    const sign = () => {

        props.navigation.navigate("Signup")

    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container} >
            <ScrollView style={styles.scroll} >
                <View style={styles.main}>
                    <Text style={styles.error}> {message} </Text>
                    < Text style={styles.label} >
                        Username:
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Username"
                        onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)} value={username}
                        autoCapitalize={'none'}
                    />

                    <Text style={styles.label}> Password: </Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Password" onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
                        value={password} secureTextEntry={true} autoCapitalize={'none'}
                    />


                    <Button onPress={() => log()} title="Login" > </Button>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
            < View style={styles.footer} >
                <Button onPress={() => sign()} title="Don't have an acount? Sign up now" />
            </View>
            < StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
    )
}

Login.navigationOptions = screenProps => ({
    headerLeft: () => null,
    gestureEnabled: false,
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'black'
    },
    headerTintColor: 'white',

})
```

Comment: I get "Unexpected reserved word 'await'." when I put await in front of the 'ch' variable and the setStringValue(...)

Comment: Try to use my Full Code

Answer (score 1):

A quick tip.

Whenever you receive a output like this:

```
Promise {

"_U": 0,

"_V": 0,

"_W": null,

"_X": null,
}
```

This means that the Promise has not been properly handled.

Try to use `async/await` to get the proper output out of the promise.

## Solution

`let ch = await getData(username)`

but you will need to put `async` before the function

### Full Code

```
const log = async () => {
  fetch(`http://192.168.5.223:8000/home/login/`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);

      if (res.valid === true) {
        setStringValue(username, username);

        let ch = await getData(username);

        console.log(ch);

        if (res.set === true) {
          props.navigation.navigate("Home", { user: username });
        } else {
          props.navigation.navigate("Profile", { user: username });
        }
      } else {
        props.navigation.navigate("Login", {
          message: "username/password are incorrect",
        });
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

## Official Functions.

Rather than to create your own functions, you can directly use the offifcial functions.
Save them in your utils and use them whenever required.

### Setting Values

```
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      '@MySuperStore:key',
      'I like to save it.'
    );
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};
```

### Getting Values

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

Comment: I get "Unexpected reserved word 'await'." when I put await in front of the 'ch' variable.