# LOG {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null} inside fetch API

Tags: json, react-native, fetch-api

I am getting this error when I console data returned from function that fetch data from back end

> {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

here is below the code:

```
const events_data = [];
function getvals() {

    return fetch('http://PCIP:3000/users/timetable')
        .then((response) => response.json())

        .then((output) => {
            return addData(output, events_data);
        })


        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

function addData(data, data2) {
    data.map((d) => {
        data2.push({
            title: d.name,
            startTime: genTimeBlock(d.day, d.start_time),
            endTime: genTimeBlock(d.day, d.end_time),
            location: d.location,
            extra_descriptions: [d.extra_descriptions],
        });
    });
}


const data = getvals();
console.log(data); // the error come from here
```

I have checked answers here but nothing worked for me

[fetch API always returns {“_U”: 0, “_V”: 0, “_W”: null, “_X”: null}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906396/fetch-api-always-returns-u-0-v-0-w-null-x-null)

[How do I access promise callback value outside of the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281739/how-do-i-access-promise-callback-value-outside-of-the-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the fetch promise has not return a response yet,

There two way to solve the issue , first you create another async funciton and use it to await for the response

```
const events_data = [];
async function getvals() {

    return fetch('http://PCIP:3000/users/timetable')
        .then((response) => response.json())

        .then((output) => {
            return addData(output, events_data);
        })


        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

function addData(data, data2) {
    data.map((d) => {
        data2.push({
            title: d.name,
            startTime: genTimeBlock(d.day, d.start_time),
            endTime: genTimeBlock(d.day, d.end_time),
            location: d.location,
            extra_descriptions: [d.extra_descriptions],
        });
    });
}

async function waitForResponse() {
let resp = await getvals();

return resp;
}

const data = waitForResponse();
console.log(data); // the error come from here
```

The other way would be using state hooks, passing the return obj to state hook on response.

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to do, you will need call it inside a class or functional component to be able use it,

if you don't want to swtich to  a functional component then there is one thing we can do is

````
const test = waitForResponse()
            .then((resp)=>{
               // place your rest of code here
});
````

Comment: actually i switched to functional component and it worked for me, than you so much

Answer (score 0):

Function for API call:

```
  export const getApplication = async (URL, headers) => {
    let data;
    await fetch.get(URL, headers).then(res => data = res.data).catch(err => err);
    return data;
  }
```

You can call the API from anywhere after importing it:

```
      getApplication(`your url`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: AUTH_TOKEN,
        },
      }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```