# Why my fetch api return {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I return the value in API to a function in React Native

Here is my code

```
getTime = async (lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) => {
        let URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins='+lat1+','+lng1+'&destinations='+lat2+'%2C'+lng2+'&key=' + GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY;
    
        let response =  await fetch(URL)
        let responseJson = await response.json()
        return responseJson
        
    }
```

Here is the function I try to call it

```
callTime = () => {
        let a = await this.getTime(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2)
            .then(response => response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value)
        return a
    }
```

When I try to console.log callTime, the value is {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

I have try with [fetch API always returns {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906396/fetch-api-always-returns-u-0-v-0-w-null-x-null) and [LOG {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null} inside fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747894/log-u-0-v-0-w-null-x-null-inside-fetch-api) but it's not work for me

Hope someone can help me with this problem, it's for my final task in college

Comment: when u use `await` you should avoid using `.then()` and `.catch()` in your promise.

Comment: The opposite. `await` will either return him the desired value from the Promise or throw an error, which will stop the execution of the function. The way to catch errors when using `await` is by wrapping it with a [try-catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block.

Comment: You can use `.catch(err=>...code)` too when using `await`, instead of a `catch` block. This helps if one has multiple `fetch` inside 1 `try` block and one has different error handlers for different errors.

Comment: Remove the braces around `{response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value}` so that it returns your value. You might as well remove the `async` from `callTime` and just have `callTime = () => this.getTime(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2).then(r => r.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value)`

Comment: @Sysix thank u for the advice, can you give me an example how to use await beside using .then() and .catch()? I'm new at this field, I'm sorry before

Comment: @avi12 I've tried using try-catch block but it's just the same, it return {“_U”: 0, “_V”: 0, “_W”: null, “_X”: null}

Comment: @AmitDas I've tried this too, but it keep return {“_U”: 0, “_V”: 0, “_W”: null, “_X”: null}

Comment: @Phil didn't work sir, still same :(

Comment: @Phil okay sir, I have

Comment: Your current code won't work since `callTime` is not `async` so `await` is invalid within it. I suggest you read my previous comment again. Also, please show exactly what your _"console.log callTime"_ code looks like. I suspect this **does** answer your question. [fetch API always returns {“_U”: 0, “_V”: 0, “_W”: null, “_X”: null}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906396/fetch-api-always-returns-u-0-v-0-w-null-x-null)

Comment: @Phil sorry sir, I forgot to delete await line, it keep not working, for my console.log, it's in render return, like this

`{ console.log(this.callTime()) }`

Comment: @Phil if you need full render code, I can add it to my question

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate since it is exactly the same issue you linked in your question. `this.callTime()` returns a promise and that is what you're logging. Perhaps you want `this.callTime().then(console.log)` instead